# Why child class method is printing null ? What am i doing wrong?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Why my code is taking null as output value instead of the parameter passed on?

**Parent Class:**

```
class Language{
  protected String name;
  protected int numSpeakers;
  protected String regionsSpoken;
  protected String wordOrder;
  
  public Language(String getName, int getNumSpeakers, String getRegionsSpoken, String getWordOrder){
    this.name = getName;
    this.numSpeakers = getNumSpeakers;
    this.regionsSpoken = getRegionsSpoken;
    this.wordOrder = getWordOrder;
  }
  
  public void getInfo(){
    System.out.println(name+ " is spoken by "+numSpeakers+"  people mainly in "+regionsSpoken);
    System.out.println("The language follows the word order: "+wordOrder);
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Mayan mayanLanguage = new Mayan("Ki'che'",30000);
    mayanLanguage.getInfo();
  }
}
```

**Child Class:**

```
class Mayan extends Language {
  protected String name;
  protected int numSpeakers;
  
  Mayan(String languageName,int speakers ){
    super(languageName,speakers,"Central America","verb-object-subject");
  }
  
  @Override
  public void getInfo() {
    System.out.println(name+" is spoken by "+numSpeakers+" people mainly in Central America.");
    System.out.println("The language follows the word order: verb-object-subject");
    System.out.println("Fun fact: "+name+" is an ergative language.");
  }
}
```

I have looked into the code and tried to resolve it by making changes but nothing seems to work, I am getting stuck into what is the mistake that I am not seeing in the code.

Expected is:

> Ki'che' is spoken by 2330000 people mainly in Central America.
> The language follows the word order: verb-object-subject
> Fun fact: Ki'che' is an ergative language.

Actual is:

> null is spoken by 0 people mainly in Central America.
> The language follows the word order: verb-object-subject
> Fun fact: null is an ergative language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Mayan` you have the fields

```
protected String name;
protected int numSpeakers;
```

Removing these will fix your issue. The reason this issue is happening is because when you define the two lines above, you are hiding the two fields from `Language` and you would have to access the fields from `Language` like `super.name`, `super.numSpeakers`, etc...

Something like the following is what you are probably after.

```
public class Mayan extends Language {
    private static final String REGION = "Central America";
    private static final String WORD_ORDER = "verb-object-subject";

    public Mayan(String languageName, int speakers) {
        super(languageName, speakers, REGION, WORD_ORDER);
    }

    @Override
    public void getInfo() {
        super.getInfo();
        System.out.println("Fun fact: " + name + " is an ergative language.");
    }
}
```

---

As Gavin pointed out, the access modifiers can be restricted. If you are working within a single package for your program, you might end up with something like

*Language.java*

```
class Language {
    String name;
    private int numSpeakers;
    private String regionsSpoken;
    private String wordOrder;

    Language(String getName, int getNumSpeakers, String getRegionsSpoken, String getWordOrder) {
        this.name = getName;
        this.numSpeakers = getNumSpeakers;
        this.regionsSpoken = getRegionsSpoken;
        this.wordOrder = getWordOrder;
    }

    void getInfo() {
        System.out.println(name + " is spoken by " + numSpeakers + "  people mainly in " + regionsSpoken);
        System.out.println("The language follows the word order: " + wordOrder);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mayan mayanLanguage = new Mayan("Ki'che'",30000);
        mayanLanguage.getInfo();
    }
}
```

*Mayan.java*

```
class Mayan extends Language {
    private static final String REGION = "Central America";
    private static final String WORD_ORDER = "verb-object-subject";

    Mayan(String languageName, int speakers) {
        super(languageName, speakers, REGION, WORD_ORDER);
    }

    @Override
    void getInfo() {
        super.getInfo();
        System.out.println("Fun fact: " + name + " is an ergative language.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would go further and say  fields in `Language` should be made private and given getters.

Comment: @Gavin you are right, you can further restrict the access modifiers depending on how the OP is planning on using the code in their project

Comment: @HimanshuKandpal I'm glad I was able to help. If you feel this has solved your problem, could you hit the tick to let others know the problem has been solved. I appreciate it

Comment: @Dan totally agree, we only have the above snippet to go on, and not the full intent of the code :)